# matplotlib + locale de_DE + LaTeX = space btw. decimal separator and number

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, latex

if I run the following code with enabled LaTeX (`usetex=True`), then I get a strange spacing between the decimal comma and the first following number. Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import locale

plt.style.use('classic')
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')
plt.rc('text', usetex=False)
font = {'family':'serif','size':14}
plt.rc('font',**font)
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

a=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]
b=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]

plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

See also the attached picture for clarification: [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the LaTeX-Package `icomma` solves the problem!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import locale

plt.style.use('classic')
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
font = {'family':'serif','size':14}
plt.rc('font',**font)

# Add the following two lines to the initial code:
params= {'text.latex.preamble' : [r'\usepackage{icomma}']}
plt.rcParams.update(params)


plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

a=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]
b=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]

plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You may want to tell people *how* to use this package.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to wohoo's answer, as this didn't work for me.

Instead of the proposed

```py
params = {'text.latex.preamble' : [r'\usepackage{icomma}']}
```

I removed the square brackets and typed

```py
params= {'text.latex.preamble' : r'\usepackage{icomma}'}
```

which fixed the issue for me and removed the spacing after the comma.